# Accessing a Second Router without DHCP

Tags: networking, router, dns

I tried to post a longer, more descriptive question, but the spam filter wouldn't let me.

I have 2 routers. Before I disabled DHCP on the second router,most of the time the network would work, and sometimes it wouldn't. The client would get a "No Internet, secured" message.

Now that I've disabled DHCP on the second router, connecting to either network is fast and always gets a "Connected, Secured" status. But now I can't access the web interface of the second router. I've already read this question: [Accessing a router which isn't a DHCP server](https://superuser.com/questions/399174/accessing-a-router-which-isnt-a-dhcp-server)

And I've tried accessing the router at its old IP (10.0.0.1), but its not responding, and factory resetting the router isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you cannot reset it?  Best way forward here.  Do reset it if you can.

Otherwise follow below:

Your first try apparently had two DHCP servers which is why you had issues.

Make sure a LAN port on Router 2 is connected to a LAN port on Router 1.

Give Router 2 a Static IP on the main network (Router 1).This is in Router 2 LAN settings.

Then ensure DHCP on Router 2 is OFF.

I have had 2 routers hooked up like this for many years.

Comment: I guess OP can't do what you are suggesting, since he can't reach the admin page. So the first step should be: configure your laptop with a static address (10.0.0.2/24), attach it directly to router 2. Now you should be able to open the admin page. Don't forget to reconfigure your laptop to DHCP when you're done.

Comment: @jordynfinity  --  If you really cannot manage the second router, perhaps replace it.  Routers are generally reasonable to purchase nowadays.